# Finiteness in the universal coefficient theorem for cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the theorem and proof, we have seen that it requires the space to be finite-typed. To me, it is somehow "embarrassing" to have such a restriction...

In the proof, the key step is $$\text{Hom}(E_\cdot,\mathbb{Z})\otimes A\cong\text{Hom}(E_\cdot,A)$$
Where we require $E_{\cdot}$ to be finite-typed. Is there any way to remove the restriction and get the theorem for all topological spaces? E.g. accept some stronger axioms?

Comment: I think the deficiency is algebraic, rather than topological. You should consider replacing singular cohomology with another theory if you would like to study the spaces for which the uct fails.

Comment: The statement of UCT for cohomology I'm familiar with has no such assumptions: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+coefficient+theorem#in_terms_of_homology

Comment: Compare the statement 5.5.3 in Spanier. I haven't checked thoroughly, but think the finiteness condition is only necessary when working over a ground ring for which the higher ext groups do not disappear.